# Django + South - migration can't cast the column type - wants me to use "USING"

Tags: django, postgresql, migration, django-south

I'm getting this error when I try to run `./manage.py migrate my_app`:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "associated" cannot be cast automatically to type integer
>   HINT:  Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion.

That sounds like great advice, but I don't know exactly what *South* wants me to do.  Am I supposed to manually edit the auto-generated python migration file?  If so, how -- I don't see standard SQL in that file.  Instead, I see this:

```python
# Changing field 'MyTable.associated'
db.alter_column(u'data_mytable', 'associated', 
    self.gf('django.db.models.fields.IntegerField')()
)
```

Also, why didn't *South* pick up on this and add the `USING` clause automatically?

Comment: What was the old type of the column?

Comment: Boolean, but now I want it to be a counter.

Comment: OK, so you'd need to use `USING (CASE WHEN thecol THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`. Not surprising a generic ORM doesn't understand changing between incompatible column types while preserving data, really.

Comment: yes, but I need this to happen through the auto-generated Python migration script (which I can edit), not through writing custom SQL in the database shell.  If I have to do this stuff through custom SQL in the database shell, then I defeat the whole purpose of migrations.

Comment: You'll probably have to add a manual command to the migration to override whatever it generates. And no, no idea how to do that in your particular ORM / schema manager flavour.

Comment: Thanks for your insight and help.

Answer (score 7):

This was my dirty hack:

1. Manually added a migraton for removing the offendig field i.e

`migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='name_of_the_model',
            name='offending_field',
        )`

2. Then I changed the operation of the complaining migration from AlterField to AddField i.e

```
migrations.AddField(
        model_name='name_of_model',
        name='name_of_field',
        field=models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, to='ForeignKeyModel'),
        preserve_default=False,
    ),
```

```

Answer (score 2):

You have to substitute original `db.alter_column` with a `db.execute`:

```python
# Changing field 'MyTable.associated'
# db.alter_column(u'data_mytable', 'associated', 
#     self.gf('django.db.models.fields.IntegerField')()
# )
db.execute(
    'ALTER TABLE "data_mytable" '
    'ALTER COLUMN "associated" DROP DEFAULT, '
    'ALTER COLUMN "associated" DROP NOT NULL, '
    'ALTER COLUMN "associated" TYPE INTEGER '
    'USING '
    'CASE '
    '  WHEN FALSE THEN 0 ELSE 1 '
    'END'
)
```

Of course, `WHEN` condition may change depending of the `associated` original type.
See also this [link](http://codeinthehole.com/writing/altering-postgres-table-columns-with-south/).